# Proving that in a graph with 400 vertices, each with a valency of 201, there exists a subgraph isomorphic to $K_3$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I need to prove that a graph $G$ with 400 vertices, each of a valency 201, has a subgraph isomorphic to $K_3$

As far as I understand, I need to prove that there exists a triangle within the graph $G$, but I am not exactly certain on how to approach the problem. I suppose it is not just randomly that we have a valency of vertices slightly above half the vertices amount, but I don't know how to make use of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A triangle free graph on $n$ vertices has at most $\lfloor n^2/4 \rfloor$ edges. Let $n = 200.$ Then $G$ has $n(n+1) > n^2 = \lfloor (2n)^2/4 \rfloor$ edges, so it contains a triangle.

Answer (score 5):

Note that one does not need to apply a general theorem here. Let $u$ be any vertex of $G$, and let $v$ be one of the $201$ vertices adjacent to $u$. Let $W$ be the set of all vertices of $G$ **except** $u$ and $v$, $U$ the set of all neighbors of $u$ in $W$, and $V$ the set of all neighbors of $v$ in $W$. Then $|U|=|V|=200$, and $|W|=398$, so $|U\cap V|\ge 2$. Pick any $w\in U\cap V$, and the $\{u,v,w\}$ induces a copy of $K_3$ in $G$.

In short, not only does $G$ contain a triangle, but every edge of $G$ is an edge of at least two triangles in $G$.

Comment: gee how did you think of that sir ? genius

Comment: @ILoveMath: Honestly? Because I don't know much graph theory. I studied a little in an undergraduate combinatorics course in 1969, and I've picked up a bit over the years, but mostly I'm attacking such problems with minimal tools. Sometimes it works out well, and sometimes it's just not enough.

Comment: You are certainly the king of combinatorics in here... i always enjoy your counting arguments... I am just curious, do u mostly rely on that 1969 class? or were you able to use such combinatorial arguments in your research area?

Comment: @ILoveMath: No, I’ve learned a lot more combinatorics since then; I just haven’t done much with graph theory. My actual research was in set-theoretic topology and used almost no combinatorics — and what little it did use was infinite combinatorics.